# Unparsable MOF Query When Trying to Register Event

Tags: c++, vbscript, windows-7, wmi

**Update 2**

I accepted an answer and asked a different question elsewhere, where I am still trying to get to the bottom of this.

I don't think that one-lining this query is the answer, as I am still not getting the required results (and multi-lining queries is allowed in .mof, as shown in the URLs in comments to the answer ...

---

**Update**

I rewrote the query as a one-liner as suggested, but still got the same error! As it was still talking about lines 11-19 I knew there must be another issue. After saving a new file with the change, I reran `mofcomp` and it appears to have loaded, but the event which I have subscribed to simply does not work.

I really feel that there is not enough documentation on this topic and it is hard to work out how I am meant to debug this - any help on this would be much appreciated, even if this means using a different more appropriate method.

---

I have the following `.mof` file, which I would like to use to register an event on my system :

```
#pragma namespace("\\\\.\\root\\subscription")

instance of __EventFilter as $EventFilter
{
    Name  = "Event Filter Instance Name";
    Query = "Select * from __InstanceCreationEvent within 1 "
            "where targetInstance isa \"Cim_DirectoryContainsFile\" "
            "and targetInstance.GroupComponent = \"Win32_Directory.Name=\"c:\\\\test\"\"";
    QueryLanguage = "WQL";
    EventNamespace = "Root\\Cimv2";
};

instance of ActiveScriptEventConsumer as $Consumer
{
    Name = "TestConsumer";
    ScriptingEngine = "VBScript";
    ScriptText =
    "Set objFSO = CreateObject(\"Scripting.FileSystemObject\")\n"
    "Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(\"c:\\test\\Log.txt\", 8, True)\n"
    "objFile.WriteLine Time & \" \" & \" File Created\"\n"
    "objFile.Close\n";
    
    // Specify any other relevant properties.
};

instance of __FilterToConsumerBinding
{
    Filter = $EventFilter;
    Consumer = $Consumer;
};
```

But whenever I run the command `mfcomp myfile.mof` I am getting this error:

> Parsing MOF file: myfile.mof
>
> MOF file has been successfully parsed
>
> Storing data in the repository...
>
> An error occurred while processing item 1 defined on lines 11 - 19 in file myfile.mof:
>
> Error Number: 0x80041058, Facility: WMI
>
> Description: Unparsable query.
>
> Compiler returned error 0x80041058

This error appears to be caused by incorrect syntax in the query, but I don't understand where I have gone wrong with this - is anyone able to advise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no string concatenation or line continuation characters being used in building "Query". To keep it simple, you could put the entire query on one line.

Comment: Thanks Mike I will try that tomorrow. I am following the guide below, where they don't use any concatenation (see part 7) - I did think that was a bit weird. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28226/Creating-WMI-Permanent-Event-Subscriptions-Using-M

Comment: Hi Mike I tried this and it sort of worked but not really, this MOF wmi stuff is just not working for me and I have no idea why ...

Comment: It did indeed, however I need a way of telling whether the "parsed" query is actually querying what I need, but I'm not sure how to check this! Currently also having a look at Posh Events UI, which is a tool written in PS and it looks like it uses a different method to subscribe (using XAML files), will post here if I find anything useful!

Comment: If your question is answered, please upvote the answer and mark it as accepted. Please use a different question if you have further issues. If you find a way of doing what you need to do, you can post a separate, appropriate question and answer it yourself (and accept it as the answer). This process tends to keep the questions clean and distinct and is the preferred SO way.

Comment: Did you update the lines that build `ScriptText`? They need string concatenation and line continuation characters as well.

Comment: I don't think 1-lining the query is the answer, as I have seen multiple examples of .MOF files where strings in a `query` variable are automatically stuck together(see http://poppopret.blogspot.co.uk/2011/09/playing-with-mof-files-on-windows-for.html and the site above) - I believe the query is now being parsed, but the reason why the subscription is not working is because there is some semantic issue where I am not escaping characters properly.